# MySQL Select CURDATE and ORDER

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I already have a mySQL statement that already selects something from the database and orders it by the closet date but it selects everything and I want it to just select it and order it if 'category' is equal to a certain value say '1'.So  my question is what would that stament be would i use 'AND' here is the select stament I already have:

```
 SELECT `name` 
 FROM `event` 
 WHERE `displaydate` >= CURDATE() 
 ORDER BY `displaydate`
```

Here is what I think it would be like:

```
 SELECT `name` 
 FROM `event` 
 WHERE `category` = 1 AND `displaydate` >= CURDATE() 
 ORDER BY `displaydate`
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: did you try to executed the second query? i think you already answer your own question `:D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your statement is correct given that the first statement works and that category is an integer.

Comment: Ok haha I feel stupid for not trying it first.But glad that it works thanks anyways.